# Splice system call, what is passed to the pipe? Data or whereabouts info?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, splice

I know with a splice, we can all stay in the kernel. But I am not sure whether it is the data or the whereabouts info that get passed to the pipe.

**EDIT 1:**
Thanks @vinayak, now I know there is actually data copy to and from the pipe buffer. But then,  I just wonder why we can not just pass whereabouts and length info to the pipe?

- Within a single process, the address space is the same
- Between difference processes, it also works if the pipe buffer is linear mapped. If not, we may use the DMA address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[refer here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2006/9/29/172)

> A splice() is a system call mechanism  to do i/o from one file to
>   another file in kernel space without doing copying from/to user
>   space.It is a way of improving I/O performance. The splice system call
>   avoids all data copy from user space to kernel space & vice versa. It
>   reads from the specified offset from the input file & writes to a pipe
>   in the kernel space. There is no copying of data to user space.Then it
>   can be called to write the data from the pipe to the output file at
>   the specified/current offset.
>
> splice() works by using the pipe buffer mechanism to open a file
>   descriptor for a data source and another for a data sink then by using
>   splice() it can join the two together. In other words, splice()  work
>   on a kernel buffer that the user has control over and  moves data
>   to/from the buffer from/to an arbitrary file descriptor. Specifying 
>   offset with pipe is an error as usual. If no  offset is specified with
>   an input/output file descriptor then the current offset will be
>   assumed to be the offset specified. Currently one of the file
>   descriptor must be pipe otherwise it is an error.